# Fade in delay on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects, delay, fadein

I've stumpled on something quite nice, I've wanted to use in some upcoming project.

It's an animated opacity on load, or you can call it fade in.

I wondered if you could link some elements together (ex. 3) so `element2` only starts when `element1` is finished, and `element3` when no. 2 is?

Or should you define a delay on `element2` and multiply the delay on `element3`?

Comment: Generally this is done using [queueing](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Comment: @zzzzBov I'd be interested how it would be done using queueing, maybe you could post it as a new answer if it has any advantages.

Comment: @PhilippM, without going into too much detail, you can set up a queue on an element (i usually choose a common parent when queuing multiple elements) and [it will correctly chain out the order of interactions without needing any sort of fancy looping or calculating timings](http://jsfiddle.net/w4xZg/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you had divs, say `class="faded"`, you could fade each in on load, each in a row like this:

```
$(".faded").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
});
```

[You can view a demo of this effect here](http://jsfiddle.net/RExZs/), or [a slower version here](http://jsfiddle.net/RExZs/1/).  The `400` is for 400ms, the duration of the normal [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) speed :)

You can either use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide them on page load, like this:

```
$(".faded").hide()
```

Or do it in the CSS:

```
.faded { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could have the fadeIn on element2 begin at the completion callback time of element1:

```
 element1.fadeIn(500, function() {  
       element2.fadeIn(500, function() { 
            etc...
```

Comment: While this works for a few, it's really not pretty once you have over 3 or so :)

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't believe that these types of animation have anything in the way of a success callback, if you know how long an element will take to fade, you can use something like setTimeout() to fire off the next after the proper amount of time has passed.

Edit: I stand corrected.